# Imagem específica em uma janela modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um código que pega todas as imagens de um diretório:

```js
<script>

 var folder = "img/";
 $.ajax({
  url: folder,
  success: function (data) {
   $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
    if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
     $(".columns").append("<div class = 'column is-4' > <a data-target = 'modal_name'class = 'img-input'> <img id = 'img-card' src='" + folder + val + "'></a></div>");
    }
   });
  }
 });

</script>
```

E quando eu clico na imagem, abre uma janela modal, eu gostaria que ele abrisse essa modal com a imagem específica em que eu clico...há como? Não faço ideia.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/d3yDMqD5 página completa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não use o evento `window.onload` porque ele é assíncrono com o Ajax. Dentro dele você está tentando atribuir eventos de clique à imagens que só serão retornadas após o Ajax. desta forma, o `result.onclick` não achará as imagens no tempo de execução.

Altere o `window.onload` para uma função normal e chame-a após o retorno do Ajax.

Altere:

```
window.onload = () => {
   ...
}
```

para:

```
var Load = () => {
   document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]').forEach((result) => {
      result.onclick = (e) => {
         document.querySelector(".modal-card-body").innerHTML = e.target.outerHTML;
         let modal = document.getElementById(result.getAttribute('data-target'))
         modal.classList.toggle("is-active")
         modal.querySelector('.delete').onclick = () => { modal.classList.toggle("is-active") }
      }
   })
}
```

Veja que no `result.onclick` incluí um parâmetro `(e)` para pegar a imagem clicada e joga-la na modal com:

```
document.querySelector(".modal-card-body").innerHTML = e.target.outerHTML;
```

No Ajax, chame a função `Load()` no final do `success`:

```
var folder = "img/";
$.ajax({
   url: folder,
   success: function (data) {
      $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
         if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
            $(".columns").append("<div class = 'column is-4' > <a data-target = 'modal_name'class = 'img-input'> <img id = 'img-card' src='" + folder + val + "'></a></div>");
         }
      });
      Load();
   }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! It works